# Joining Null values

Tags: postgresql, left-join

Table 1
Table 2

```
select col1, col2, etc
from table 1
left join table 2
on table1.col1 = table2.col1
```

If table2.col1 has null values, will this somehow screw up my join results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `table2` null values do not matter in this case. Left join will match all rows from `table1` to `table2`. If a row from `table2` does not have a match in `table1` it will not appear in the result set.